# Can't type anything in to to reset admin password

Tags: password, reset

When I go to reset my password in root mode and type 
passwd lunar 
It won't let me type to change my password so I need help here the laptop I'm using is a Lenovo G580 (windows on it got corrupted so I installed Ubuntu Linux on it)

Comment: Recovery mode one

Comment: I've did that I have a video uploading

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to remount in read write mode:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now, you should be able to reset your password using the `passwd` command:

```
passwd lunar
```

enter the new password before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)